# What is the difference between changing src and innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, performance, iframe

I have multiple `iframe` in the single HTML page. Everytime user wants to reload all `iframes` there is one button which reloads every iframe.

There are following two ways how I can do it:

1. Changing `src` of each `iframe`.
2. Changing `innerHTML` of each container and adding new iframes to each container.

When I am following 2nd approach and trying to load every iframe multiple times browser getting stuck. But it's not happening in 1st approach.

Which is best and fast way to do it? Which is better?

Comment: _"Which is best and fast way to do it? Which is better?"_ -> _"When I am following 2nd approach and trying to load every iframe multiple times browser getting stuck. But it's not happening in 1st approach."_

Comment: Reloading an iframe, why not just run `.contentWindow.location.reload()`?

Comment: @Andreas is 1st way is better?